# created a bootstrap nav bar angular app but when it comes to mobile responsive it is not closing default on click

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, components, angular7, navbar

here i have home.html

**home.html**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top bg-light" id="mob-res">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed ml-auto" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar"
        aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Notes List</span>
        <span>&#9776;</span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand px-2" routerLink="['/notes-list']"> Notes App </a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right scrollbar">
        <app-notes-list></app-notes-list>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-12 bg-light height">
      <div id="desk-view" class="scrollbar">
        <h3 class="text-center p-3" routerLink="['/notes-list']">Notes App</h3>
        <app-notes-list></app-notes-list>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
  </div>
```

**notes-list.html**

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-start py-3 px-2">
  <div class="px-2">
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="inputText" (input)="search()" placeholder="Search"
      style="background:transparent;width: 100%;
      border: none;
      border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(212, 192, 192);">
  </div>
  <div class="px-2 ml-auto">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onAddNewNote()">Add Note</button>
    </div>
</div> 
<div class="d-flex" *ngIf="notes.length == 0">
    <h5 class="text-center">No data found. Please search with another keyword</h5>
  </div>
<div *ngFor="let note of notes;let i = index">
<app-note [notes]="note" [index] = "i"></app-note>
</div>
```

and with in this im calling app-notes-list. In this i have one more child component called app-note

**.note.html**

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column py-4" [routerLink]="[index]" style="cursor:pointer;">
    <div class="px-2">{{notes.name | shorten:40}}</div>
    <div class="px-2">{{notes.createdOn | date:'shortTime'}}</div>
  </div>
  <hr>
```

here when it comes to mobile responsive it shows navbar and when i click on navbar and selected one it is redirecting but the navbar is not closed

Comment: may be your css is not imported correctly. Can I see your angular.json

Comment: isn't that the default behavior of bootstrap-4 navbar?